# Create DataAnnotation to make sure user has specified one type of email address and there is a default

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I have a Person class in which a person can have 3 types of email address - Home, Work, Other.

At least one of these must be specified, and a default email address must be specified - which is just a boolean.

I'm to try this with a DataAnnotation (if that's the correct way?!)

Any ideas how I can code this DataAnnotation?

```
public class Email
{
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public bool? Default { get; set; }
}

public class PersonEmail
{
    public Email Home { get; set; }

    public Email Work { get; set; }

    public Email Other { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{

    //Other property goes here
    //Other property goes here
    //Other property goes here
    //Other property goes here

    [MyDefaultEmailAddressValidation]   
    public PersonEmail Email { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Is this the entity class that is mapped to db table?

Comment: No...this isn;t going to be entity framework or anything. This will be used in WebApi to accept a person's details and make sure that 1) an email has been specified and 2) Only one of them is marked as default.

Comment: Can you change these models ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create another property to check if all 3 addresses are *empty*, and with a data annotation that this new property has a *range* that can only accept *true*.

Example:

```
    [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "The field Email must be informed.")]
    public bool IsEmailInformed
    {
        get
        {
            return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Home.Address) == false ||
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(Work.Address) == false ||
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(Other.Address) == false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd make `Person` class the `IValidatableObject` and check weather it's valid whenever it's necessary.

```
public class Person : IValidatableObject
{
    public PersonEmail Email {get;set;}

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if (Email.Home == null && Email.Work == null && Email.Other == null)
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("At least one email address have to be provided!"));
        return results;
    }
}
```